# Manage Client Usernames & Passwords

Tags: security

What do you guys use to manage all your clients' login credentials?  For each client I have 4-5 sets of usernames and passwords saved in an encrypted excel spreadsheet.  I hate doing it this way.

I'm looking for some kind of software or service that can:

- Save my client contact info, notes, etc
- Securely store the various credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really specify what the login credentials were used for but I'd recommend you take a look at implementing a SQL database ([MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), [PostgresSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), etc)  for this. You can encrypt the passwords via a hashing algorithm (usually SHA-1 or MD5). You can also add everything else (client contact info, notes, etc) in the database.

Comment: I use the credentials for my records... for example my clients will have ftp credentials, google analytics creds, etc.

Comment: Your clients must have a lot of trust in you. Is this excel spreadsheet encrypted via password protection? It can be broken pretty quickly if that's the case. Really, the best bet is to use a database and you'll be able to store all this data in an easy to lookup way.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://www.mypasswords7.com/ ?

I have tried it and use it for 3 years.